# Responding to Manipulation delta - strange effect and overflow

Tags: touch, uwp

In a test UWP form I have a basic manipulation test, code below. It draws 3 circles on a CanvasControl and sets up translation and scaling manipulation.

When I test this on a touch screen it basically does what I expect, translating and zooming the circles based on the position of 2 fingers on the screen. But if I pinch down beyond a certain point, the image starts to oscillate very quickly between 2 extents and will very quickly cause the code to stop with an overflow.

I put the canvas control in a grid and tried doing the manipulation on the canvas control from the grid control, and it does not suffer from the same problem although the effect of zooming and panning does not seem correct.

So it looks like the effect of my code as is, is an iteration, where a manipulation causing a render transform change could cause another manipulation, and it goes in circles until it settles - or if there is a problem of precision, perhaps due to the distance between the touch points getting too small, the iteration diverges until overflow.

Is this expected? What is the correct way to do this?

```
Private WithEvents Canv As New CanvasControl
Private WithEvents gr As New Grid


Private Sub Canv_Draw(sender As CanvasControl, args As CanvasDrawEventArgs) Handles Canv.Draw
    args.DrawingSession.DrawCircle(50, 50, 25, Windows.UI.Colors.Blue)
    args.DrawingSession.DrawCircle(250, 250, 25, Windows.UI.Colors.Blue)
    args.DrawingSession.DrawCircle(500, 500, 25, Windows.UI.Colors.Blue)
End Sub

Public Sub New()

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

    Content = gr
    gr.Children.Add(Canv)


    Canv.ManipulationMode = ManipulationModes.Scale Or ManipulationModes.TranslateX Or ManipulationModes.TranslateY

end sub


Private Sub Canv_ManipulationDelta(sender As Object, e As ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs) Handles Canv.ManipulationDelta
    Dim t As New TranslateTransform

    t.X = e.Cumulative.Translation.X
    t.Y = e.Cumulative.Translation.Y


    Dim s As New ScaleTransform
    s.ScaleX = e.Cumulative.Scale
    s.ScaleY = e.Cumulative.Scale
    s.CenterX = e.Position.X
    s.CenterY = e.Position.Y

    Dim g As New TransformGroup
    g.Children.Add(s)
    g.Children.Add(t)

    Canv.RenderTransform = g



End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The common way in UWP is to use [CompositeTransform](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br228105), it supports **Scale, Skew, Rotate and Translate**.

Please see the BasicInput sample, especially [the forth scenario](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/BasicInput/vb/4-XAMLManipulations.xaml.vb)

For the zooming issue, you can avoid it by using the following way:

```
Public NotInheritable Class MainPage
Inherits Page

Private WithEvents Canv As New CanvasControl
Private WithEvents gr As New Grid

Private Sub Canv_Draw(sender As CanvasControl, args As CanvasDrawEventArgs) Handles Canv.Draw
    args.DrawingSession.DrawCircle(50, 50, 25, Windows.UI.Colors.Blue)
    args.DrawingSession.DrawCircle(250, 250, 25, Windows.UI.Colors.Blue)
    args.DrawingSession.DrawCircle(500, 500, 25, Windows.UI.Colors.Blue)
End Sub

Public Sub New()

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

    Content = gr
    gr.Children.Add(Canv)

    Canv.ManipulationMode = ManipulationModes.Scale Or ManipulationModes.TranslateX Or ManipulationModes.TranslateY

End Sub

Private Sub Canv_ManipulationDelta(sender As Object, e As ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs) Handles Canv.ManipulationDelta
    Dim tran = Transform(sender)
    tran.ScaleX = tran.ScaleX * e.Delta.Scale
    tran.ScaleY = tran.ScaleY * e.Delta.Scale
    'System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("tran.ScaleX =" + tran.ScaleX.ToString() + " tran.ScaleY =" + tran.ScaleY.ToString())
End Sub

Private Function Transform(sender As Object) As CompositeTransform
    Dim rect = TryCast(sender, CanvasControl)
    rect.RenderTransformOrigin = New Point(0.5, 0.5)
    Dim tran As New CompositeTransform
    If TryCast(rect.RenderTransform, CompositeTransform) IsNot Nothing Then
        tran = DirectCast(rect.RenderTransform, CompositeTransform)
    Else
        rect.RenderTransform = New CompositeTransform()
    End If
    Return tran
End Function

' utility method
Private Function Boundary(value As Double, min As Double, max As Double) As Double
    If value > max Then
        Return max
    ElseIf value < min Then
        Return min
    Else
        Return value
    End If
End Function
End Class
```

**Screenshot:**
[image: Gif]

Answer (score 0):

Some useful information in that, in the meantime I found a tidy solution, which was to leave the CanvasControl in the grid, and take the manipulation events from the grid and change the rendertransform of the Canvas control, that way there is no recursion. It also means that the natural translation is not correct - but this is easy to fix by multiplying it by the cumulative scale, ie. the full manipulation code becomes:

```
Private Sub GerberCanvGrid_ManipulationDelta(sender As Object, e As ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs) Handles GerberCanvGrid.ManipulationDelta
    Dim sf As New ScaleTransform
    sf.ScaleX = e.Cumulative.Scale
    sf.ScaleY = e.Cumulative.Scale
    sf.CenterX = e.Position.X
    sf.CenterY = e.Position.Y

    Dim tt As New TranslateTransform
    tt.X = e.Cumulative.Translation.X * e.Cumulative.Scale
    tt.Y = e.Cumulative.Translation.Y * e.Cumulative.Scale

    ManipulationTransform = New TransformGroup
    ManipulationTransform.Children.Add(sf)
    ManipulationTransform.Children.Add(tt)
    GerberCanv.RenderTransform = ManipulationTransform
End Sub
```